# How to create a row rdd from a list in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a row from a  list in pyspark. My Main task is to create a dataframe from the nested list that i have.

```
a = [i for i in df_dict.values()]
```

which looks like

```
[[203,40000,HR],[204,5000,Engineering]....]]
```

df_dict.values contains data in list form for multiple columns. the contents of Mylist are supposed to be the headers of the respective lists within a.

```
Mylist=["id","Salary","department"]
```

I want to create a row which will be header for my dataframe and then a dataframe using the below code.

```
R = Row(listToString(mylist1))
sp=spark.createDataFrame([R(*i) for i in zip(*a)])
```

I am getting the result if I hardcode this

Example

```
R= Row("id","Salary","department")
```

But if u try to do the same by converting existing list into Row, it is taking this as a single row. I even tried changing the input of list to string but it did not give me the required result.

```
R = Row(listToString(mylist1))
```

list to string is a function I have created to convert list into string to be used as input for row fuction but it is not working.

Comment: Do you want an RDD https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-parallelize-create-rdd/ or a dataframe (which is what an `RDD[Row]` is)? https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/

Comment: The main task is to create a dataframe through a nested list.

Comment: Your question doesn't have a nested list. Please show a [mcve] of your full input data

Comment: edited and added more details in the question

Comment: Did you see the second link I put above? It shows data very similar

Answer (score 0):

> `[i for i in df_dict.values()]`

1. This is the same as just `[df_dict.values()]`.
2. Unless you have lists as values in your dictionary, this wouldn't be a list of lists.

---

Regarding converting to a dataframe, or RDD, see

See https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/

Example with a list of dictionaries, which I convert into a list-of-lists as `rows`

```
data = [{
    'id': 203,
    'salary': 40000,
    'dept':'HR'
}, {
    'id': 204,
    'salary': 5000,
    'dept': 'Engineering'
}]

headers = data[0].keys()
rows = [tuple(d.values()) for d in data]

spark.createDataFrame(rows).toDF(*headers).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+------+-----------+
|id |salary|dept       |
+---+------+-----------+
|203|40000 |HR         |
|204|5000  |Engineering|
+---+------+-----------+
```

Comment: In this , you have taken dictionaries in a list.In my case it is a nested list and I want to parse it into a dataframe. Could you please help me on how to create dataframe  from a nested list?

Comment: My `rows` is a list of tuples

Comment: When you use `df_dict.values()`, this would only give you one list. You therefore don't need a list of lists.